# for each element, onclick change values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, foreach

i have use nodejs handle bar to create a for each table :

```
<tbody>
    {{#each result}}    
        <tr>
            <td id="engagementTotal">{{data.engagementTotal}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

But i need to change the values  of each value by an onclick function, i tried to use

```
for (var i=0; i < positiveTotal.length; i++){
    sEngagementTotal.push(positiveTotal[i].data.engagementTotal);
}

document.getElementById("engagementTotal").innerHTML = sEngagementTotal;
```

but the above only change the first table's value

Comment: You use the same id for multiple items in single document?

Comment: yes because the <tr><td> elements generate by a for each loop

Comment: update complete tbody tag on click function using client side handlebar. check http://handlebarsjs.com/ for more details

Comment: sorry , i am new to handlebars and i don't understand what you are saying

Comment: ids must be unique, use classes instead

Answer (score 1):

Instead of depending upon id depend upon class

```
<tbody>
    {{#each result}}    
        <tr>
            <td id="engagementTotal" class="demo">{{data.engagementTotal}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>

for (var i=0; i < positiveTotal.length; i++){
    sEngagementTotal.push(positiveTotal[i].data.engagementTotal);
}

document.getElementByClass("demo").innerHTML = sEngagementTotal;
```

Comment: So if i got an Array like ['10','20','30'],  am i able to insert them to each table i 've got?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?